# I need a way to store information offline using a web-app

Tags: html, css, manifest

I want to create a web-app using HTML5, CSS3 and possible JQuery mobile. This app will just be a form used to collect customer data but it needs to be able to work offline.

I've created offline web-apps before and used manifest files to make them offline but is there a way to make a form store data on the device for uploading to a computer or server later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions for offline storage in HTML5, but all depend on which browser you want to support? `localStorage` is perhaps the most widely supported at the moment, there was also web SQL databases and so forth: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

Comment: I want to be able to use my app on an iPad. Would localStorage allow me to transfer the data I have collected to a computer later on?

Comment: Yes: http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage although it would be a manual process to parse the saved data and to sync it with the server. It's definitely possible as I've done it in the past.